# Using Perl to change the url homepage for Internet Explorer

Tags: perl, internet-explorer, url

I am using Perl only, and I am trying to code-in the lines that would change the homapage url for Internet Explorer after running this Perl program.

*I am using the header 'use Win32::OLE' which calls on a system file.

*This code is error-free.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Win32::OLE;

print "What url would you like to make as Internet Explorer's home page?\n";
print "(no spaces, the url as you normally see it on the address bar)\n";
chomp($url=<STDIN>);

while (!$url)
{
    print "You did not make and entry! Please enter a url.\n";
    chomp($url=<STDIN>);
}

while ($url)
{
    if ($url =~ /\s/)
    {
        print "That's not a url! You entered a space somewhere. Re-enter:\n";
        chomp($url=<STDIN>);
    }


    *CODE FOR SETTING HOMEPAGE IN INTERNET EXPLORER HERE*


    print "\nYour home page in IE has been changed! Re-open IE and see!";
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Win32::TieRegistry (https://metacpan.org/module/ADAMK/Win32-TieRegistry-0.26/lib/Win32/TieRegistry.pm) to edit the registry to set:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Start Page"="http://www.example.com/"
```

Comment: When you run what? You should edit your question appropriately. (That's .reg file syntax.)

Comment: I have a Perl script I am running. This is a Perl script program like I stated on the title.

Comment: You should post the relevant code if you need help figuring out why you get an error.

Comment: Edit it into the original question.

Comment: This answer does not apply to the code. So I cant approve it.

Comment: @user-jose2384656: Wait, what? It's a perfectly applicable answer — if you have even a basic understanding of Perl, you should be able to read the documentation to understand how to apply it. **We will not write your code for you.**

Comment: Registry...is basic? lol Most definitely not! But I will take some time to investigate it in the future. Thanks!